# How to randomize the name entered by the user

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, visual-c++-2017

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int jumlah_orang;
    char user3;
    vector<string> names;
    string nama;
    srand(time(NULL));
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Jumlah Orang: "; cin >> jumlah_orang;
        cin.ignore();
        for(int i = 0; i < jumlah_orang; i++)
        {
            cout << "Nama ke-" << i+1 << ": ";
            getline(cin, nama);
            names.push_back(nama);
        }
        cout << "\nNama:\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << names[i] << endl;
        }
        int random_name = rand() % names.size();
        cout << nama[random_name] << endl;
        cout << "\nUlang Program? (Y/T): "; 
        cin >> user3;
    }
    while(user3 == 'Y' || user3 == 'y');
    getch();
}
```

The name that comes out is always in the form of one character. For example, enter the name "Russel". The output can be "u", "s", "l", etc. This is not what I want.

I want users to enter the number of users and enter their respective names. When random is done, the output data is the name of one of the users entered.

Comment: Shouldn't the `cout` be `names[random_name]` instead of `nama[random_name]`? `nama` contains the last entered name and is a string. So `nama[random_name]` is a character.(it can also lead to undefined behavior if random_name > nama.length())

Comment: thanks man, my code is work now @kuro